Select rows based on desired date difference from first row by group - SQL
I can generate a table with the following structure - in actuality, this is more than 50,000 rows long - but below example is a simplified representation:
Row    Account Number     Date
1      1001               2011-01-10
2      1001               2011-02-01
3      1001               2011-02-20
4      1001               2011-02-22
5      2001               2011-04-11
6      2001               2012-01-01
7      2001               2012-01-30
8      2001               2012-02-09

I would like to select the first row and next row for each account number where the date difference is at least 30-days.
So in the example above, I would like to select Rows #1 and #3 for Account Number 1001, Rows #5 and #6 for Account Number 2001.
How to generate this (in snowflake SQL)?

You say you want the rows selected to be at least 30 days apart, but rows 1 and 2 for account number 1001 is only 20 days apart. I would have assumed rows 1 and 3 would be selected instead. I don't think I understand what you are asking for.

fixed typos, thank you. Correct, I want to select 1 and 3 as you said.

To pick the rows that first have a gap of 30 days, the first date of the pair will always be the first date, thus we are trying to find the first date and the next date with accumulative gap thus:
with example_data as (
    select * from values
     (1, 1001, '2011-01-10'::date),
     (2, 1001, '2011-02-01'::date),
     (3, 1001, '2011-02-20'::date),
     (4, 1001, '2011-02-22'::date),
     (5, 2001, '2011-04-11'::date),
     (6, 2001, '2012-01-01'::date),
     (7, 2001, '2012-01-30'::date),
     (8, 2001, '2012-02-09'::date)
     as t(rn, Account_Number, Date)
)
select *
    ,first_value(date) over (partition by Account_Number order by date) as f_date
    ,datediff('days', f_date, date) as gap
    ,gap >= 30 as valid
from example_data
order by rn;

gives:



RN
ACCOUNT_NUMBER
DATE
F_DATE
GAP
VALID




1
1001
2011-01-10
2011-01-10
0
FALSE


2
1001
2011-02-01
2011-01-10
22
FALSE


3
1001
2011-02-20
2011-01-10
41
TRUE


4
1001
2011-02-22
2011-01-10
43
TRUE


5
2001
2011-04-11
2011-04-11
0
FALSE


6
2001
2012-01-01
2011-04-11
265
TRUE


7
2001
2012-01-30
2011-04-11
294
TRUE


8
2001
2012-02-09
2011-04-11
304
TRUE



now we want to run over this and keep the first of each valid
so we need to do a nested operation to allow the two window function that correct scope so that happen correctly:
select *
    ,row_number() over (partition by Account_Number, valid order by date) as keep_1
from (
    select *
        ,first_value(date) over (partition by Account_Number order by date) as f_date
        ,datediff('days', f_date, date) as gap
        ,gap >= 30 as valid
    from example_data
)
order by rn;


which we can then use a QUALIFY to trim down:
select *
from (
    select *
        ,first_value(date) over (partition by Account_Number order by date) as f_date
        ,datediff('days', f_date, date) as gap
        ,gap >= 30 as valid
    from example_data
)
qualify date = f_date OR (valid AND row_number() over (partition by Account_Number, valid order by date) = 1)
order by rn;


and then we can exclude the columns we don't want:
select * exclude (f_date, gap, valid)
from (
    select *
        ,first_value(date) over (partition by Account_Number order by date) as f_date
        ,datediff('days', f_date, date) as gap
        ,gap >= 30 as valid
    from example_data
)
qualify date = f_date OR (valid AND row_number() over (partition by Account_Number, valid order by date) = 1)
order by rn;




RN
ACCOUNT_NUMBER
DATE




1
1001
2011-01-10


3
1001
2011-02-20


5
2001
2011-04-11


6
2001
2012-01-01




I'm trying to imagine a way of pulling this that doesn't have an interim result set with a slight cross-join involved, but I'm not sure it's possible. One option:
SELECT t1.row, t1.accountnumber, t1.date as firstdate, t2.row as 30dayplusrow, t2.date as 30dayplusdate
FROM yourtable t1 
    INNER JOIN yourtable t2
       ON t1.accountnumber = t2.accountnumber
       AND DATEADD(day, 2, t1.date) >= t2.date 
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY accountnumber ORDER BY firstdate, 30dayplusdate) = 1


See example
select * 
from(
  select * ,sum(d1)over(partition by account_number order by date)sd1
  from(
    select *
      ,datediff('days',lag(date,1,date)
                  over(partition by account_number order by date),date)d1
    from test
  )a
)b
where sd1=0 or (sd1>=30 and (sd1-d1)<30)



To select the rows as per your criteria in Snowflake SQL, you can use a combination of window functions and a common table expression (CTE). Here's an example query that achieves this:
    WITH ranked_data AS (
    SELECT
        Row,
        Account_Number,
        Date,
        LEAD(Date) OVER (PARTITION BY Account_Number ORDER BY Date) AS Next_Date
    FROM
        your_table_name
)
SELECT
    Row,
    Account_Number,
    Date
FROM
    ranked_data
WHERE
    DATEDIFF(DAY, Date, Next_Date) >= 30 OR Next_Date IS NULL;

In this query:
We first create a CTE named ranked_data where we use the LEAD window function to get the next date for each account number.
Then we select the rows from the CTE where the date difference is at least 30 days or where the next date is null (which means it's the last row for that account).
Row    Account_Number    Date
1      1001              2011-01-10
3      1001              2011-02-20
5      2001              2011-04-11
6      2001              2012-01-01
enter code here


down voted because when using the provide data, the "shown results" are not what this SQL produces. Also row is a reserved word, so not valid, so this SQL has not been run on snowflake.

if the question was "find the earliest row that has a 30 day gap between it and the next row (ordered by date)) then this is a fine answer.

An answer that does not run, gives different results than claimed and does not follow the instructions of the questions, is by diffention not a good answer. The comment/down vote was to say, "not good" now if they change there answer, and the new answer ether works, follows the instrustions, or gives a novel "may you ment this" then I will remove my down vote. But I don't wish to work in a work in a world where people failing to do the tasks are required to be given "valueable co-worker" awards.
